# What are the prerequisites for topos theory?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation, topos-theory

*This might be too vague or too broad if we're not careful. Therefore, let's focus on the basics. According to [this MSE search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Prerequisites+for+topos+theory+), this is new to MSE.*

### Some Background:

I have read Goldblatt's, *"Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic,"* - although [Chapter 14](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3525776/104041) is where I stopped doing its exercises altogether, which I had been gradually neglecting as I read the text. It covers some ground in its opening chapters.

In [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531554/for-any-ring-r-prove-that-r-mathbfmod-has-no-subobject-classifier#comment7263458_3531554) on a question of mine, three books on category theory were recommended.

I'm reading Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic: A First Introduction to Topos Theory."* Its very first chapter is on categorical prerequisites and I have read it.

[Around 2013](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/554195/104041), I read most (if not all) of Turi's *"Category Theory Lecture Notes"* from The University of Edinburgh. I've forgotten most of it though.

### The Question:

> What are the prerequisites for topos theory?

### Context:

I am teaching myself topos theory because I find it fascinating and I enjoy the challenge.

I'm not sure where I get this notion from but I'm given to understand that algebraic geometry plays a rôle in topos  theory. I did a module on algebraic geometry in the final year of my MMath.

The same goes for topology.

I have included the [book-recommendation](/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) tag because, as above, some of you might feel it best that I read some other books before continuing with Mac Lane and Moerdijk's.

Please help :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a useful comment or not, but I'm currently part way through Lawvere and Schanuel's *Conceptual Mathematics*, which will introduce me to topos theory by the end, and which starts at almost kindergarten level with absolutely no prerequisites whatsoever.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/828843/104041)

Comment: In case you are just interested in the internal language of toposes, large parts of the categorical analysis of toposes is not required for a first familiarization. I tried to give a short account of this [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.00948).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would follow the advice of the first paragraph of my edition of Mac Lane-Moerdijk, which is to go read sections of Mac Lane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician* that expand on the topics treated in Chapter 1, and to solve their exercises. Other books, most notably Riehl's *Category Theory in Context*, are now often recommended as a first introduction to category theory. These have some improvements over Mac Lane, but it might be that the best preparation for Mac Lane-Moerdijk is Mac Lane himself. Either way should be fine. Turi's notes look nice but you want many more exercises.

Comment: Ah, yes; it's in my copy too. Thank you :)